# How to download a bunch of files from many links on an open browser window?

Tags: download

Okay, this one is hard to classify for me because I don't know the solution yet.

There are these credit card statements that I have to download from my bank's website, but the crazy thing is that they have one separate pdf file for each month - that's like 60 files for last 5 years - and I need to go through all those transactions!

So, being lazy as I am not to just download them one by one, I was wondering if I could write a script or a simple program that can just download these files once I have the browser window open.

Now the key is this - the program cannot directly make an http call to the bank's website, because this window is behind an account authorization screen, after a few clicks to get to credit card statements. What I want to do, is just open the window, and then run some program, and voila, all the files are downloaded.

And just for some super-kicks, it would be awesome if the program could read those pdf files, parse the tables in the pdf and put them into a spreadsheet or something - if someone tells me how to do that in a few hours, you'll get some serious respect and love.. but even the above should be good enough..

Comment: DownThemAll for firefox.

Comment: wow.. there is an firefox-app for that already?! Nice.. Thanks! Although, I'd really love to see how to program this too maybe as a desktop app..

Comment: Oh bummer - these buggers have disabled the browser toolbar, right clicks, resize...

Comment: There is still no answer on this? This isn't a regular problem for everyone now is it?

Comment: @Roopesh Shenoy: The question is too vague. Language? Platform? Current attempts? Why not use a premade solution?

Comment: Currently, I don't care which language allows me to do this. And I mentioned up there, the premade solution you suggested DownThemAll does not work in this scenario. So my question is still open.